# Trim mobile numbers in textarea field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a textarea field in a form where I can copy paste (or type) mobile numbers. It will have one number per line, like this I can copy paste (or type) thousands of mobile numbers to submit in that form. 
I want to trim that field, I only want 10 digit numbers to remain in that field after copy paste (or type). 
Only valid 10 digit numbers should remain and all other invalid numbers should automatically remove from that field. 
Example: 
If I paste this numbers in this textarea field,

> 9848012345 
> 9949123450 
> 9949 123456 
> 99491234 
> 99491234561 
> +1236547890 
> 9848098765

From this only 10 digit numbers should remain in field, like this:

> 9848012345 
> 9949123450 
> 9848098765

```
<div class="form-group row">
     <label for="title" class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Mobile Numbers </label>                         
   <div class="col-lg-10">
     <textarea onKeyUp="countline()" type="text" class="form-control required" required 
cols="10" rows="7" id="mobileno" name="mobileno"> </textarea>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
     <label class="col-lg-2 control-label " for="userName">Number Count </label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control " readonly id="numbercount" required name="numbercount" value="">
  </div>
 </div>
```

Using this script (onKeyUp="countline()") to count numbers (lines). Need to keep this also.

```
<script>
    function countline() {
        var length = $('#mobileno').val().split("\n").length;
        document.getElementById("numbercount").value = length;
    }
</script>
```

Any help please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This produces the desired output however it does not count the digits, only the characters.

```js
const
  textArea = document.getElementById("mobileno"),
  validateEl = document.getElementById("validate");

validateEl.addEventListener("click", validate);

function validate(e) {  
  const filtered = textArea.value
    .split("\n")
    .filter(number => number.length === 10)
    .join("\n");

  textArea.value = filtered;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group row">
     <label for="title" class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Mobile Numbers </label>                         
     <div class="col-lg-10">
       <textarea type="text" class="form-control required" required 
  cols="10" rows="7" id="mobileno" name="mobileno"></textarea>
      <button id="validate">Validate</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working for copy paste, but I can not type numbers in this field. Some time I also need to type numbers in this field.

Comment: How is this supposed to work during typing? As long as you're typing the number won't ben 10 digits and get removed...

Comment: @Ravi I added a button to my answer but if you wanted a button, why do you have an onKeyUp event?

Comment: @robill it doesn't hence the note. The OP used an onKeyUp event and asked for copy-paste.

Comment: @Undo using onKeyUp="countline()"  to count added numbers. Check I have updated my code. After this update my number count will not work? I need to count&show numbers.

Comment: @Ravi OK, that's not relevant to the question nor my answer, can you instead elaborate on how this does not answer your question?

Comment: @Undo your answer solved my requirement. But, I lost  onKeyUp="countline()" functionality to count numbers! This I must have. Any solution ?

Comment: @Undo When using this button is in form, when click Validate it submits form and form main functionality lost and count also not working. Thank you for your time.